# how to get this symbol with Latex?

Tags: symbols, math-operators

here is the picture of this symbol:

[image]

How should I do to get it in math-mode? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be `\mathfrak{X}` from the `amssymb` package. You can find this out yourself using http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html.

Comment: or using my service http://write-math.com